# List manipulation: position & max value combination

Tags: list-manipulation

Starting with

```
{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 2}, {2, 3, 3}, {3, 4, 5}}
```

I would like to get

```
{{0, 2, 3, 5}, {1, 3, 2, 3}}
```

where the first list returned is the highest value reached in each of the first lists, and the second output is the position of the highest values that were reached in each list.

I have been trying different combinations of `Max` and `Position`, but have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
dat = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 2}, {2, 3, 3}, {3, 4, 5}};

f[a_] := {#, Position[a, #, 1, 1][[1, 1]]} & @ Max[a]

Transpose[f /@ dat]
```

> ```
> {{0, 2, 3, 5}, {1, 3, 2, 3}}
> ```

---

Since your lists are "very long" here is a faster method using my favorite trick: SparseArray Properties.

```
f2[a_] := {#, First @ SparseArray[UnitStep[a - #]]["AdjacencyLists"]} & @ Max @ a

Transpose[f2 /@ dat]
```

> ```
> {{0, 2, 3, 5}, {1, 3, 2, 3}}
> ```

Performance comparison on a big array:

```
dat = RandomInteger[1*^9, {1000, 100000}];

Transpose[f /@ dat]  // Timing // First
Transpose[f2 /@ dat] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 3.9
>
> 0.515
> ```

---

#### Update

Reminded of this question it occurs to me that R.M's [`Ordering`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering.html) solution can be modified to give the desired output by negating the list:

```
f3[x_] := {x[[#]], #} & @@ Ordering[-x, 1]
```

Compared in *Mathematica* 10.1:

```
r2 = Transpose[f2 /@ dat]; // RepeatedTiming
r3 = Transpose[f3 /@ dat]; // RepeatedTiming

r2 === r3
```

> ```
> {0.649, Null}
>
> {0.478, Null}
>
> True
> ```

Comment: @ Mr Wizard, thanks for the time you have given to this - I will test once _Mathematica_ has evaluated what I have given it!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard you do have a fast computer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28209/hardware-performance-metrics-for-mathematica

Comment: @s0rce I use version 7 which seems to be faster than later versions in a number of cases of basic programming.  But yes, I have found clock speed to correlate well with *Mathematica* performance and I run an unlocked i5-2500K CPU at 4.6 GHz.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `f2` is surprisingly much faster than the typical `C` solution, when compiled (on my computer).

Comment: @VF1 That's an interesting finding.  I know that the code behind `SparseArray` generation is highly optimized which is why it often outperforms more obvious and direct solutions, at least in version 7.  Have you tried compiling `Position` to C?  I recall someone reporting that as being very fast.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard see my posted answer

Comment: @VF1 pardon me, what answer?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard the one I just posted on this very question.

Comment: @VF1 I know I'm supposed to be a wizard but I can't see into the future. :-p

Answer (score 12):

Using `Ordering` is another option, and more efficient if you have long lists/sublists:

```
dat = {{0, 1, 0}, {3, 1, 2}, {2, 3, 4}, {5, 3, 4}}; (* different example with a unique max *)
With[{l = #}, Composition[{l[[#]], #} &, Last, Ordering]@#] & /@ dat // Transpose
(* {{1, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 1, 3, 1}} *)
```

Note that if you have more than one element that is the maximum, then `Ordering` will only give you the last index.

Comment: But that's not the example that martin gave; I assume he specifically chose an example with repeated maximums, and wanted only the first position.

Comment: I have *very* long lists! Many thanks :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Well, we don't know and that's the problem with underspecified questions :)

Comment: @ Mr Wizard, that is true - will try all now

Comment: @martin Which result do you actually want?

Comment: Have just accepted :)

Comment: @ rm -rf, thanks for editing - apologies if not clear

Answer (score 5):

Another option:

```
list = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 2}, {2, 3, 3}, {3, 4, 5}}

maxWithPosition[list_] := 
 With[{max = Max /@ list}, {max, 
   MapThread[Position, {list, max}][[All, 1, 1]]}]

maxWithPosition[list]
```

> ```
> {{0, 2, 3, 5}, {1, 3, 2, 3}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Using `PositionLargest` (new in V 13.2)

```
{Max /@ list, First @* PositionLargest /@ list}
```

{{0, 2, 3, 5}, {1, 3, 2, 3}}

In combination with `Query`:

```
Query[Transpose, {Max, First @* PositionLargest}] @ list
```

{{0, 2, 3, 5}, {1, 3, 2, 3}}

```
Query[All, {Max, First @* PositionLargest}] @ list
```

{{0, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {5, 3}}

With `TakeLargestBy` (new in V 10.1)

```
Join @@ Map[TakeLargestBy[# -> {"Element", "Index"}, Identity, 1] &, list]
```

{{0, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {5, 3}}

One advantage of `TakeLargestBy` is that we can use functions like `Abs` or `Length` to compare elements.

Answer (score 3):

If speed is an issue, and you're using numeric values, I would go for `Compile`. This will only work for data types that are compilable, such as `_Integer` or `_Real`, but those seem to be the only ones OP is interested in.

Here's the fastest I could come up with:

```
Module[{cfn1},
 cfn1 = Compile[{{list, _Integer, 1}},
        Module[{temp, max = First@list, maxp = 1},
     Do[temp = list[[i]]; 
      If[temp > max, max = temp; maxp = i], {i, Length@list}];
     {max, maxp}
     ], CompilationTarget -> "C"];
 singlePassC[arg : {__Integer}] := cfn1[arg];
 singlePassC[{}] = {};
 ]
```

I noticed some interesting timing trends, though, compared to Mr.Wizard's function. Consider the more *Mathematica*-like `Compile`d implementation for finding the maximum position:

```
Module[{cfn1},
 cfn1 = Compile[{{list, _Integer, 1}},
    With[{max = Max@list}, {{{max}}, Position[list, max]}],
    CompilationTarget -> "C"];
 twoPassC[arg : {__Integer}] := cfn1[arg][[All, 1, 1]];
 twoPassC[{}] = {};
 ]
     (* Mr. Wizard's non-compiled implementation *)
sparseArrayME[
  a_] := {#, First@SparseArray[UnitStep[a - #]]["AdjacencyLists"]} &@ Max@a
```

All of these work:

```
sparseArrayME@{3, 5, 4} ===
 singlePassC@{3, 5, 4} ===
 twoPassC@{3, 5, 4} ===
 {5, 2}
 (* True *)
```

But notice these peculiar timings:

```
dat = RandomInteger[1*^9, {100000000}];
datm = RandomInteger[1*^9, {1000, 100000}];
test[f_] := f@dat // Timing // First
testm[f_] := f /@ datm // Transpose // Timing // First
funcs = {sparseArrayME, singlePassC, twoPassC};
{{"Data Type", "Sparse Array", "Single Pass C", "Two Pass C"},
  Prepend[test /@ funcs, "Single Array"],
  Prepend[testm /@ funcs, "Matrix"]} // TableForm
```

[image: results]

So Mr.Wizard's *uncompiled* `SparseArray` properties is faster than a compiled `Position` when applied to many smaller-sized sublists. I doubt this is because of the deeper nesting I am forced to make in `twoPassC`'s `cfn1` which I then extract from in the actual function - that shouldn't be what takes so long.

Answer (score 2):

Using `GroupBy`:

```
lst = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 2}, {2, 3, 3}, {3, 4, 5}};

Transpose@Map[{#, Last@First@Position[lst, #]} &, Keys[GroupBy[lst, Max]]]

{{0, 2, 3, 5}, {1, 3, 2, 3}}
```