# Finding positions of minimum values in list

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to find the positions of multiple occurrences of a minimum value in a list. For instance, for the list {1, 2, 1, 3}, I want to obtain the two positions for the occurrences of the number 1.

MinimalBy[{1, 2, 1, 3}, id (x)] gives me these occurrences, but not the positions.

Comment: `MinimalBy[Range@Length@list, list[[#]] &]`?

Comment: Or modifying [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40232/4999): `minpos[a_] := SparseArray[UnitStep[# - a]]["AdjacencyLists"] &@Min@a` and then `minpos[list]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40231/list-manipulation-position-max-value-combination

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
lst = {1, 2, 1, 3};
Random`Private`PositionsOf[lst, Min @ lst]
```

> {1, 3}

Also

```
 Flatten@Position[lst, Min @ lst]
```

> {1, 3}

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {1, 2, 1, 3}
PositionIndex[list][Min[list]]
```

> {1, 3}

Comment: Even more appropriate for the task is: :PositionSmallest[list]

Comment: @MichaelWeyrauch You should write it as an answer. I am running v12.2.0 which is a few years old.

Answer (score 3):

o.k. as suggested by Syed, here comes my answer: As of Mathematica Version 13.2:

```
list={1,2,1,3}
PositionSmallest[list]
```

{1, 3}

Also there is:

```
PositionLargest[list]
```

{4}

Comment: I love the new `PositionSmallest` and `PositionLargest` functions---significantly cleaner syntax for this common issue. I am left scratching my head, however, as to how it took until v13.x for them to be introduced...